# Passing data from VC to VC segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am using this code to pass a object to another view controller.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Detail"]){
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        DetailedViewController *controller = (DetailedViewController *)navController.topViewController;
        controller.clipping = [pasteBoardArray objectAtIndex:_row];
    }
}
```

On the line of:

```
DetailedViewController *controller = (DetailedViewController *)navController.topViewController;
```

I get a lengthy exception

```
2014-05-20 18:46:39.752 SWTableViewCell[8370:60b] -[DetailedViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10c7169e0
2014-05-20 18:46:39.756 SWTableViewCell[8370:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DetailedViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10c7169e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102667495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001016c699e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001026f865d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102658d8d ___forwarding___ + 973
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102658938 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   SWTableViewCell                     0x000000010000d91c -[ViewController prepareForSegue:sender:] + 204
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001004f4c73 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 134
    7   SWTableViewCell                     0x000000010000c4be -[ViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 350
    8   SWTableViewCell                     0x00000001000089ae -[SWTableViewCell selectCell] + 798
    9   SWTableViewCell                     0x000000010000864b -[SWTableViewCell scrollViewTapped:] + 171
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000100362fc2 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 188
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000100361f28 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 357
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001003662d9 ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke + 53
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000100366261 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 257
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010035e337 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 93
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000100072a15 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 928
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001000736d4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 909
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010004b29a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 211
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000100038aed _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 9579
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001025f6d21 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001025f65f2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010261246f __CFRunLoopRun + 767
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102611d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001025c6f04 GSEventRunModal + 161
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010003ae33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    25  SWTableViewCell                     0x0000000100002763 main + 115
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010607f5fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

As a side note I am doing this all within a `UINavigationBarController`. All I need to do is pass `objectAtIndex:_row` to the `_clipping` property in the `DetailedViewController`.

Comment: Do you have a Navigation Controller between your first viewController and your DetailedViewController?

Comment: This is how I have my storyboard setup: http://i.imgur.com/fQPQUGD.png

Comment: Can you give us details about your segue? Is it starting from your first viewController or from your cell?

Comment: @user1966109 it is starting from my cell.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code if there is NO navigation controller BETWEEN your two view controllers:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Detail"]){
        DetailedViewController *controller = (DetailedViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        controller.clipping = [pasteBoardArray objectAtIndex:_row];
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Use the following code only if there is ONE navigation controller BETWEEN your two view controllers:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Detail"]){
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        DetailedViewController *controller = (DetailedViewController *)navController.topViewController;
        controller.clipping = [pasteBoardArray objectAtIndex:_row];
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted is the same as I posted, and still causes the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you posted suggests that the destination view controller of your segue is not a navigation controller as you think it is. You should log the class of the destination view controller to see what it is.